# Geographical location in google maps

Tags: sql-server, google-maps, asp.net-web-api, gis, angular-google-maps

I'm working on project that deals with advertisements and google maps. I save every advertisement latitude and longitude in my database, but I want to add an option that show user on the map and show all available advertisement around it with radius of 1 km, but I don't know how, Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an interesting project. These are the steps I suggest you :

- Store you latitude/longitude as a `geography` data type using SQL Server. See [geography (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx).
- From your webpage, retrieve the user location. See [Use Geolocation API with Angular.js](http://victorshi.com/blog/post/Use-Geolocation-API-with-Angularjs).
- Send back the position to your web api (create a new action into your controller).
- Write a stored procedure that take the user position as parameter and return the advertisement around it with radius of 1 km. See [SQL Geometry find all points in a radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670198/sql-geometry-find-all-points-in-a-radius) (Geography and Geometry have quiet the same functionalities).
- Send the Advertisement location to the client side and use Google Map to show it (I am sure you're going to find some good tuto about that).

Good luck !